# Algorithm/heuristic for large tournament matchup pairings

Tags: algorithms, scheduling, heuristics

I'm scheduling a large invitational tournament with the following conditions

1. The event takes place over 8 weeks
2. Teams arrive and depart on different dates/times, so each day of the event will have a different number of teams available to play
3. Teams will play only once per day
4. Teams have specific criteria they ask for, which means

   - Some pairs of teams can not play (e.g. teams requested not to play each other)
   - Some pairs would be a better matchup than others (e.g. similar skill level). I can create a score for a matchup based on the two teams' preferences (perhaps on a scale of 1-100).

My desired output would be a set of matchups per day which optimizes for highest combined score of matchups for the entire event. The solution does not have to be optimal, but should be close. This is something I would run only once, so speed is not very important.

What is a good algorithm/heuristic to approach this problem?

Comment: Are pairings be allowed to repeat on different days?

Comment: Beware. The criteria you have specified may well not be the real ones. Suppose, for instance, that you find your algorithm and run it, and it gives you an optimum-scoring result in which three of the teams *have just one match each*. You may well find that you will have to go back and insert additional scoring criteria to avoid this kind of outcome. On the other hand, that probably makes the whole exercise more fun! **Suggestion:** take a much smaller version of the problem and try solving it by hand to get a better understanding of what a “good” and a “bad” solution might be.

Comment: Teams shouldn't repeat, unless that is the only possibility for the day (e.g. only the same four teams in town for two consecutive days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach is to use integer linear programming (ILP).  This is basically an operations research problem, and ILP is a powerful tool for problems like this.

You can introduce zero-or-one integer variables $x_{i,j,d}$, with the intended meaning that $x_{i,j,d}=1$ means that teams $i,j$ play each other on day $d$.  Each of your constraints can be expressed using linear inequalities.  The objective is a linear function of the variables, i.e., $\sum_{i,j,d} s_{i,j} x_{i,j,d}$, where $s_{i,j}$ is the score for the matchup between teams $i$ and $j$.  Then, you can feed this to an off-the-shelf ILP solver, such as Gurobi or CPLEX, and it will (hopefully) find for you the optimal schedule.